# Use of Image in HTML Meta tags

Tags: html, image

I am going to use images in HTML Meta tag.
I need to know what type of images user will uses in Meta tag i.e logo Or images that are used in the website?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking here. Can you edit your question to a clear question?

Comment: `<meta>` is a semi-generic way to provide metadata about a document. What sort of images you use with it depend on what sort of metadata you are setting.

Comment: Thanks for your replies friends.